# Styling ControlsFX searchableComboBox from controlsfx 11.1.2

Tags: combobox, controlsfx

My style classes:

```
.searchable-combo-box {
    -fx-background-color: transparent;
    -fx-background-insets: 0;
    -fx-background-radius: 0;
    -fx-border-width: 0 0 1 0;
    -fx-border-color: #053445;
    -fx-border-radius: 0;
    -fx-prompt-text-fill: gray;
}

.searchable-combo-box:focused {
    -fx-background-color: transparent;
    -fx-background-insets: 0;
    -fx-background-radius: 0;
    -fx-border-width: 0 0 1 0;
    -fx-border-color: #1291bf;
    -fx-border-radius: 0;
    -fx-prompt-text-fill: gray;
}

.searchable-combo-box .combo-box-base .text-field {
    -fx-background-color: transparent;
    -fx-background-insets: 0;
    -fx-background-radius: 0;
    -fx-text-fill: black;
}
```

It doesn't work when I start typing on my searchableComboBox.
The 'focused' behavior is not working.